# Conductive coating for aluminium

Tags: electrical

What would be the best conductive coating for aluminium for good electrical contact and that isn't too expensive ?

The goal is to use aluminium as conductive busbar and would like to avoid the formation of aluminium oxide.

One I found that could perhaps work is the IRIDITE® 14-2 Chromate Coating

Comment: What is this busbar for? This sounds pretty out of scope for DIY.SE....

Comment: Electrical wiring of the house

Comment: Your circuit breaker panel should already have a neutral and ground connection bar. You can also purchase ready made additional screw terminal connection bars to add more connection points to an existing panel if required. What ever you are thinking about trying to come up on you own for house mains wiring you should stop. Use only listed parts applied in a manner that follows the electrical code requirements.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: @Damien -- is this within an enclosure of some sort? What is connected to this busbar?

Answer (score 1):

Bus bar in a house? I doubt it would be code compliant, at least not here in North America.

Aluminum bus bars used in switchgear and panels are tin plated to guard against corrosion. Connections to aluminum devices are coated with Nolox compound.

Answer (score 0):

Noalox, deox, ox guard are all anti-oxidant compounds for aluminum, cheap insurance when using aluminum. A small tube under $5 at any big box store. I use them all the time, especially when close to the coast. On residential I coat the screws on the main lugs and it prevents gauling, even on copper wire it is cheap insurance and a larger bottle lasts me months - just a dab will do.